# RxJava - why is my switchMap() so slow to switch?

Tags: javafx, rx-java, reactive-programming

I made an interesting discovery at work, and I'm hoping one of the RxJava gurus can explain it. I'm using RxJava 1.2.4.

I was using [RxJavaFX](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX) to emit table selection events from a JavaFX `TableView` (these emit on the JavaFX thread), and put them in a `switchMap()`to kick off an expensive process for each one. I use the `switchMap()` with a `subscribeOn()` inside to not only leverage concurrency, but also if I rapidly make multiple selections, the previous requests are cancelled and the latest one starts next.

```
tableSelectionEvents.switchMap {
        runExpensiveProcess(it)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap { anotherExpensiveProcess(it) }
                .toList()
    }.observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.getInstance()).subscribe {
        backingList.setAll(it)
    }
```

However, I noticed the JavaFX UI was horribly laggy as I made selections, meaning the JavaFX thread was still doing a significant amount of work. This puzzled me because I thought I used the `Schedulers.io()` inside the `switchMap()` to offload the work on another thread, and indeed this was the case. But something else was going on.

I had a hunch and then put an `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` right before the `switchMap()`. Now everything runs perfectly and there is no lag at all. My theory is that the incoming thread (originally the JavaFX thread, now the IO thread), has to do substantial work in cancelling the last subscription inside the `switchMap()`. This made the JavaFX thread spend a significant amount of time executing the cancellation and thus freezing up the UI.

Is calling `unSubscribe()` within the `switchMap()` that expensive?

Comment: How is `runExpensiveProcess` implemented?

Comment: Some expensive RxJava-JDBC queries are what's driving it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got some assistance from Jake Wharton on another forum. He highlighted what I was already starting to suspect. Some subscriptions are more expensive than others to unsubscribe. In this case, I think my usage of RxJava-JDBC resulted in a lot of query overhead that needed to be disposed, and the JavaFX thread became occupied doing this.

He also told me this is what the `unsubscribeOn()` operator is for. It allows specifying a scheduler for the execution of the unsubscription.

```
tableSelectionEvents.switchMap {
        runExpensiveProcess(it)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap { anotherExpensiveProcess(it) }
                .toList()
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }.observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.getInstance()).subscribe {
        backingList.setAll(it)
    }
```